# Автоскроллинг вниз

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт который при переходи по ссылке запускает страницу с самого низа, тоесть крутить колёсиком вниз уже не надо.
Как заставить этот скрипт ещё выполнять функцию когда обновляешь на этой страничке, если перед обновлением колесо крутанул чуть в верх, то после обновления всё остаётся в том же положении, а надо что бы обратно в самый низ пролистало, так же как при переходе на эту ссылку

```html
 window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('bottom').scrollIntoView(true);
}

<div id="bottom"> //листается до этого дива
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чем проблема? Используйте при загрузке и каждом обновлении страницы следующий код:

```
el.scrollTop = Math.ceil(el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight);
```

Где  el - это страница или элемент, где требуется все промотать вниз, а округление нужно для точности позиционирования на экранах с высоким разрешением.

Comment: а можно готовый код, я просто новичок в этом деле

Comment: если скроллинг для основного окна, то    
    document.body.scrollTop = Math.ceil(document.body.scrollHeight - document.body.clientHeight);

Comment: если для любого отдельного элемента страницы, то document.getElementById('id').scrollTop = Math.ceil(document.getElementById('id').scrollHeight - document.getElementById('id').clientHeight); id - соответственно id окна, в котором делается промотка.